# Не работает async|await в visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

В 2010 студии не работает `async` | `await`. Как показали зарубежные источники, не хватает обновления (т е библиотеки). Какой библиотеки не хватает - ясно. Где она должна лежать - не ясно. Вопрос: можно ли добиться работы `async` | `await` на VS 2010??

Comment: Я бы посоветовал перейти на VS 2017, она бесплатна для некоммерческой разработки и куда лучше старых версий.

Comment: @VladD ага, и комп за одно новый купить...всякой фигни в нее посовали, а чтобы ее выключить можно было, кому она не надо не сделали...

Comment: Почему не сделали? Посмотрите в Инсталлятор, там можно отключить довольно много.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет.

Только начиная с VS2012 можно завести `async`/`await` в Visual Studio.

Comment: Спасибо большое)